# wpf form does not redraw

Tags: c#, wpf, plugins, autodesk-navisworks

I have made plugin for autodesk navisworks with wpf. It have a form that should be filled in after mouse down event.

```
public override bool MouseDown(...)
{
    ...
    //wpf Form
    WPFControl wpf = new WPFControl();

    //GetProperty - method that cleares all items
    //then creates tab control, tab items and fills gridview
    wpf.GetProperty();

}
```

First time after initialization wpf form fills, but then it does not redraw. However, tab control, tab items and grid view changes in debug mode. I can't understand why it does not redraw.

At the same time programmatically added button with GetProperty method refreshes wpf form.

```
private void btnChooseTemp_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     GetProperty();
}
```

Comment: Use `wpf.UpdateLayout();`

Comment: From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.updatelayout(v=vs.110).aspx) about `UpdateLayout`: *Calling this method has no effect if layout is unchanged*. Better use `InvalidateVisual`.

Comment: Unfortenatelly this methods don't help.

Comment: Try this :  `wpf.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
          wpf.InvalidateVisual(); wpf.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;`

Comment: No, it does not. It can redraw form if I don't call form class `WPFControl wpf = new WPFControl();`